# Modifying Arrays in Swift, (Inserting and Appending via Subscript Syntax)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So I've been doing some experiments with Swift's array. And discovered some few things with the following codes below:

```
var shoppingList = ["Chocolate", "Bread", "Cheese", "Apple"]
println(shoppingList)
shoppingList[2..<2] = ["Butter", "Milk"] //Question #1 (Insert after 2nd element)
println(shoppingList)
shoppingList[0..<0] = ["Coffee"]
println(shoppingList)
shoppingList[7..<7] = ["Berry", "Pie"] //Question #2 (Append at the end of array)
println(shoppingList)
```

Gives the following output:

```
[Chocolate, Bread, Cheese, Apple]
[Chocolate, Bread, Butter, Milk, Cheese, Apple]
[Coffee, Chocolate, Bread, Butter, Milk, Cheese, Apple]
[Coffee, Chocolate, Bread, Butter, Milk, Cheese, Apple, Berry, Pie]
```

**Question #1:** Experimenting with the `subscript` syntax, it seems that using `..<` will `Insert` an item to the array to the given position (which in my sample is after 2nd element via `[2..<2]`. As opposed to call array's `insert(_:atIndex:)` method, does this have any differences on **performance**? Or depending on the scenario, **readability** will just be the benefit of using `insert()`?

**Question #2:** According to Swift's documentation here: [Collection Type - See Modifying/Accessing Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105)

> NOTE
>
> You can’t use subscript syntax to append a new item to the end of an
>   array.

Then my question is why was I able to append 2 elements, "Berry" and "Pie" to the end of array by using `[7..<7]`?

I am using *Swift 1.2* at the time of this writing.

Comment: Question #2: I guess the note refers to the `shoppingList[] = "Berry"` syntax used in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a great question, so I've had a play around.


Looking at the example of subscripting with `7..<7`, the half-open range operator `..<` is creating a `Range` struct that looks like this:

```
let range = 7..<7
print(range.startIndex)    // 7
print(range.endIndex)      // 7
```

Which is perhaps obvious. But what impact does a range with an end index beyond the array bounds have on the array subscript? The subscript function declaration looks like this:

```
subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element>
```

And if we were to call

```
let shoppingList = ["Coffee", "Chocolate", "Bread", "Butter", "Milk", "Cheese", "Apple"]
let item = shoppingList[6..<7]
// item: ArraySlice<Int> = "Apple"
```

We get back a slice of "Apple", which you would expect - we've asked for a slice of `shoppingList` containing elements at indexes 6 or higher and indexes lower than 7, so we get back a slice with a single item at index 6.

Also note this behaviour:

```
let item = shoppingList[6...6]
print(range.startIndex)    // 6
print(range.endIndex)      // 7
```

The `endIndex` is actually `7`, but looking at the subscript above you wouldn't expect any problems, and you wouldn't get any. One way to look at this is to say that the `endIndex` of the sub range is the index of the first array element **not** to be included in the array slice. We can assume that the subscript implementation bounds-checks with this in mind.

So what might an implementation of this subscript's getter look like? Let's try it:

```
extension Array {
    func myRangeSubscript(subRange: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        if count < subRange.endIndex { fatalError("Out of bounds!") } 

        var slice = ArraySlice<Element>()
        for i in subRange {
            slice.append(self[i])
        }
        return slice
    }
}
```

When passing in `7..<7`, since no integer exists for `x` where`7 >= x < 7`, the for loop isn't entered once. That clears up why `shoppingList[7..<7]` works, despite appearing at first glance to be indexing out of bounds.

It's only a small step further to consider what the subscript *assignment* might look like:

```
subscript(subRange: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
    get {
        //...
    }
    set(newElements) {
        // newElements: Array<Element> = []
        self.removeRange(subRange)
        var elementIndex = 0
        for i in subRange {
            self.insert(newElements[elementIndex++], atIndex: i)
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps the reason you can apparently "append" to the end of the array despite the documentation saying otherwise, is that semantically you're not actually appending - you're *replacing* a range of elements in the array with a new array of elements. It just so happens that with the `n..<n` range, you're replacing an *empty* array of elements with your new array. Technically, perhaps, not an append/insert, but a rather quirky replace! So while the docs might be technically correct, in practice they just don't consider this edge case.

---

Briefly, regarding the question of performance, I cannot say with certainty how the subscript is actually implemented. But it seems obvious that it would take *at least* as long to perform an insert using this range subscript as it would to use `insert(_:atIndex:)` or the single index subscript (which very likely calls through to `insert(_:atIndex:)` anyway), since there *could* be some overhead in preparing for an `ArraySlice` to be created, or for a call to `removeRange(_:)`.

For this reason, and the fact that it is less readable and not semantically reflecting what you're trying to do, I would avoid using this range subscript to insert array items. Just stick with `insert(_:atIndex:)` or the corresponding subscript - that's what they're there for!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, experimenting with `print(shoppingList[7..<7])` results to an empty array `[]` which is really odd, thinking that it is already out-of-bounds. But your explanation makes sense, that it may be a rather quirky replace. I wonder why did they allow it though...

Answer (score 0):

Playing with `Array` in Swift is quite interesting!

> **Answer to Question 1:**

The subscript is only use when you need to enter value in range. In case, if you want enter a single value then subscript is not efficient way.

**E.g.:** `shoppingList[1..<1] = ["Coffee"]` <- Which is quite wrong way!

Instead of that, you can just go for below code:

```
shoppingList.insert("Your Data", atIndex: 1)
```

> **Answer to Question 2:**

You can enter two elements at place `[7..<7]` because your shoppingList Array ends at 6 and 7 comes after it and also you have specify range.

Although, you can insert new item like below:

```
shoppingList.insert("Your Data", atIndex: 7)
```

But when you try to insert like below, you will surely get an error saying "**index out of bound**".

E.g.:

```
shoppingList.insert("Your Data", atIndex: 10)
```

Because you array ends at index 6! Similarly, you can't insert range too.

```
shoppingList[8..<10] = ["Data", "Data"]
```